# Monkey patch the node js bunyan logging

Tags: node.js, logging, bunyan

Do you have an idea on how to monkey patch the node js bunyan methods like info, debug by using shimmer(https://www.npmjs.com/package/shimmer) ?

For example, this is my bunyan configuration:

```
let bunyanLog = require('bunyan')
let bunyanOpts = {
  name : "bunyan-logging",
  level : "debug"
}

let bunyanLogger = bunyanLog.createLogger(bunyanOpts)
```

So, in my app I can call

```
bunyanLogger.info('info message') // output: info message
```

I want to monkey patch this `bunyanLogger.info()` by adding another functionality.
So when executing the `bunyanLogger.info()` we also send a Facebook/Slack notifications.

I could not find articles or tutorials in the net about monkey patching the bunyan. Thanks!

Comment: Try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan-sql-stream). You can configure bunyan to log to a database using streams.

Comment: @CarloCorradini I'm sorry but I don't want to use any 3rd party libraries. I want to have a solution by using monkey patching for **flexibility reason**. Thanks.

Comment: The code is very simple, you can copy and make your changes to it. See the source(one file | 50 lines) at [this](https://github.com/fdesjardins/bunyan-sql-stream/blob/master/index.js) link.

Comment: Looks like the bunyan module itself does not expose an `info()` method, but you always have to instantiate a logger. Can you modify the `bunyan.createLogger()` call? If you can, then it's easy to sneak in a custom stream class that does things.